# how to distribute a list of lists to other elements in a new list. haskell

Tags: haskell

For example lets say i have a list **(x:xs) = [[x], [y], [z]]**. How would i convert it to **[Object n [x], Object n [y], Object n [z]].**
Where Object and n are the same in all elements.

Answer (score 2):

To apply the same function to all the elements of a list you can use `map`, as follows:

```
map (Object n) yourList
```